# Validation on confirming Alert

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function FinalFunction() {
         //Your First Script
         return  confirm('Are you sure about to submit the test?');
     }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:FinalFunction();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

This script is showing the confirmation alert message but either on clicking OK or Cancel Button, the page is redirecting to another page.

What I want is when I click on the Cancel Button, the page should be on same page, it should not redirect to another page.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OnClientClick = "return FinalFunction();"?

Comment: if i don't want to show alert msg in btn click A in some page and in some other page on same btn click A i want to show that alert box.. is it possible if yes then how

Comment: try to add dynamically on Page_load the attribute "OnClientClick" for the button, and if it's on the desired page make it to return false, if not, just call your function or Redirect to the page you want

Comment: i have 6 btns in that page, shall i add the attribute for all 6 btns

Comment: you go with a foreach through all rows, then you find the control of the row with Button btn = row.FindControl("myButton") as Button. And so you do: btn.Attributes.Add("OnclientClick", "return false;") or btn.Attributes.Add("OnclientClick", "return false;").. depending on your if condition.

Comment: can u please say me the foreach loop how could i do that, please don't give me theoretical explanation help me by writing some code

Comment: foreach(DataRow dr in GridView1){ Button btn = dr.FindControl("Button1")as Button; if(drisdesiredRow){btn.Attributes.Add("OnclientClick", "return false;"); else  btn.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "javascript:: return FinalFunction();")}} something like this. is not 100% sintactic good. Just do this thing for your code, adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

modify your function:

```
function FinalFunction() {
    confirm('xxx');
    return false;
}
```

but when would you like to redirect your page?

Comment: sorry for that, I get the wrong answer :(, just change your HTML to `OnClientClick="return FunalFunction();"`

Comment: if i don't want to show alert msg in btn click A in some page and in some other page on same btn click A i want to show that alert box.. is it possible if yes then how

Answer (score 0):

The button does a postback, do you redirect to another page in your .NET code-behind class?

Comment: if i don't want to show alert msg in btn click A in some page and in some other page on same btn click A i want to show that alert box.. is it possible if yes then how